# ActiveMQ: How to get all messages in a queue for Receiver (Java)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic

Here is the Server's code:

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection;
public class Server{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        StompConnection con = new StompConnection();
        con.open("localhost", 61618);
        con.connect("admin", "admin123");
        con.begin("a1");
        con.send("/queue/test1", "This is test message 1");
        con.send("/queue/test1", "This is test message 2");
        con.send("/queue/test1", "This is test message 3");
        con.commit("a1");
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Client's code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompFrame;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.Stomp.Headers.Subscribe;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //login.
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        String pass = in.next();
        if (!"123".equals(pass)){
            System.out.println("Sorry, wrong password.");

        }
        else
        {
            StompConnection con= new StompConnection();
            con.open("localhost", 61618);
            con.connect("admin", "admin123");
            con.subscribe("/queue/test1", Subscribe.AckModeValues.CLIENT);
            con.begin("a2");
            StompFrame mes = con.receive();
            System.out.println(mes.getBody());
            con.ack(message, "a2");
            con.commit("a2");               
            con.disconnect();
        }


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I have 3 messages on Server. However, I only can get 1 message per time in Client. How to get all the messages in the queue in a run? Anyone can help me?

Comment: PSA: "Java" is not supposed to be written in allcaps. It's not an acronym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you've tried here but to read all three is just a simple loop like:

```
    con.begin("a2");
    while (true) {
        StompFrame message = null;
        try {
            message = connection.receive(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(mes.getBody());
        con.ack(message, "a2");
    }
    connection.commit("a2");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is just simple and how come I couldn't figure it out~